# jquery divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='../images.jpg' alt='images' />
</div>
```

I want to put this image in div with jquery

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='some_class'><img src='../images.jpg' alt='images' /></div>
</div>
```

Tnaks!

sorry, I'd like tu put in this div not onli this images but  element also ???

ex:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='some_class'>
       <img src='../images.jpg' alt='images' />
        <strong>text</strong>
   </div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".container img").wrap("<div class=\"some_class\"></div>");
```

[Check out the Wrap documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap#html)

Comment: sorry, but I can put in this div not onli image but <strong> element also ??? 

<div class='container'>
   <div class='some_class'><img src='../images.jpg' alt='images' />
   <strong>text</strong>
</div>
</div>

Comment: In that case, I'd use something like: $(".some_class").append("<strong>text</strong>"); right after you executed the the Wrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an id for the image, you can use wrap:

```
$("#myimg").wrap("<div class='some_class'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use
wrap inner plug in

```
<script>
$('.myimage').wrapInner('<div><\/div>');
</script>
```

http://motherrussia.polyester.se/jquery/wrapinner/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, easy and quick:

```
$(".container img").wrap("<div class='some_class'></div>");
```

You can also build the nodes yourself, but with jquery this is a fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".container img").wrap('<div class="some_class"></div>')
```

There are some great documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page